# How to use Fuzzy GUI editor in Scilab?

Tags: gui, scilab

I've installed [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/sciFLT) for Scilab 5.4.1

In Matlab we can write `fuzzy` in command line and use that.

How to use Fuzzy GUI editor in Scilab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Fuzzy GUI Editor we need to download this Toolbox.

You can download it from [here](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/sciFLT#comment2089). And then extract it some where like `~/flt/`.

And then we need to load this Toolbox on Scilab, as below :

1. Open Scilab
2. Type below command in Scilab command line and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to load Fuzzy Logic Toolbox :

   ```
   exec("~/flt/loader.sce");
   ```

Finally you can use below command to use Fuzzy GUI Editor:

```
editfls
```

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> in the home directory in order to show the invisible directories. Find `.scilab` and browse to `.scilab/scilab-5.5.0/atoms/`. When you're inside this directory, create a new folder called `sciFLT`. Now, if you have the module downloaded in to your computer, paste it into this new folder you've just created (you can download it [here](http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/sciFLT/0.4.4)).

Now, with your scilab opened you'll execute the command

```
atomsInstall('/home/.Scilab/scilab-5.5.0/atoms/sciFLT/name_of_the_file_you_just_dowloaded.tag.gz');
```

Hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to execute, then restart scilab, and probably you'll be good to go!

To access the GUI fuzzy module use the command `editfls`!